# How to add if condition to prevent blank task adding in react todo app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created a simple todo app here, when press enter button the task will push to an array but when add press without adding any text to the input area, still the bullet symbol will appear.

How to prevent this by using if condition?

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Basictodo2 extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      title: "Map arrray when press the enter button ",
      input: "",
      list: []
    };
  }

  changeHandler = t => {
    this.setState({
      input: t.target.value
    });
  };

  pressEnter = e => {
    //  var l = this.state.list;
    var i = this.state.input;
    if (e.which === 13) {
      //    l.push(i)
      this.state.list.push(i);
      this.setState({
        //    list : l,
        list: this.state.list,
        input: ""
      });
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  };

  render() {
    var { title, input, list } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <form>
          <h2>{title}</h2>
          <input
            onKeyDown={this.pressEnter}
            type="text"
            value={input}
            onChange={this.changeHandler}
          />

          <div>
            <ol>
              {list.map(data => {
                return <li>{data}</li>;
              })}
            </ol>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Basictodo2;
```

Comment: you want to add the to do item only if it is not null? Am i getting it right?

Comment: yes, when there is no any text input but when press enter, then nothing should be displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this approach

if i is not null then only this will execute

```
var i = this.state.input;
if(i){//then do something

  if (e.which === 13) {
  //    l.push(i)
  this.state.list.push(i);
  }
}
```

Comment: i tried if(i===''){ return null} ---but this is not working here.:(

Comment: replace if(i==='') to if(!i)

Comment: blank and null are not equal. Here it is null, so i==='' wont execute

Comment: You should never mutate the state like this: "this.state.list.push(i)". Instead use setState();

Answer (score 0):

If you don't wont to empty values to be submitted you should make the field as required by adding `required` attribute to the input field.

You can add if condition to check if value is not null before pushing to array like:

```
if(i) {
  // code to push to array
}
```

Comment: its working now but what is the meaning exactly for if(i){ ? means if there is input is blank then the code shoud be pushed to the array ? why cant we use      if(i===''){ here ?

Answer (score 0):

You can check `i` to see if it contains anything. Like this

```
   if (e.which === 13) {       
      if (i) {
        const list = [...this.state.list, i]; 

        this.setState({
          list,
          input: ""
        });
      }

      e.preventDefault();
    }
```

So on `enter` you check if `i` is not empty (empty strings are [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy)), and then you add it to your state. You prevent default either case so you don't refresh the page on empty input submit.

See this codesanbox for details: https://codesandbox.io/s/14jy6jmm04

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have a major mistake in your code, you are modifying the state without the setState() function. So delete this line of code:

```
this.state.list.push(i);
```

Next you need to retrieve the value of the input and check if it has a falsey value(0, empty string, null). If it does, you prevent the default behavior and return from the function. You can retrieve the value from the e.target.value

```
pressEnter = e => {
   var i = this.state.input;
    let value = e.target.value;
    if (e.which === 13) {
      if (!value) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return;
     }
```

After that you need to create a **new array** which will include the new input and update the state.

```
  this.setState({
    //    list : l,
    list: [...this.state.list, value], // this is a new array
    input: ""
  });
```

In the end you will also need to add a  unique key to the 'ul' elements. You can use the index of the element in the list.

```
  {list.map((data, index) => {
    return <li key={index}>data</li>;
  })}
```

Here is a link to the working code:

https://codesandbox.io/s/5y0747y7yp